# Pandas copy values from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas dataframe df1 contains a list of values A

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','b']})

   A
0  a
1  a
2  b
```

Dataframe df2 can be seen as mapping from values in A to values in B

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b'], 'B':[2,3]})

   A  B
0  a  2
1  b  3
```

I want to apply the mapping to df1. The working version I have is this one, but I feel there is potential for improvement, as I find my solution unreadable and I am unsure about how it would generalize to multiindexes

```
df2.set_index('A').loc[df1.set_index('A').index].reset_index()
   A  B
0  a  2
1  a  2
2  b  3
```

I could also convert df2 to a dictionary and use the replace method, but it does not convince me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) function for this, which accepts a dict or series, in the latter it uses the index to perform the lookup:

```
In [94]:
df1['A'].map(df2.set_index('A')['B'])

Out[94]:
0    2
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [93]:    
%timeit df1['A'].map(df2.set_index('A')['B'])
%timeit df1.merge(df2, on='A')
1000 loops, best of 3: 718 µs per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop
```

On your test data [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) is nearly 2x faster I would expect this to be true for large data also as it's cython optimised and doesn't need to do as much checking as [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge).

Comment: Although .merge is great, I feel this is the better answer as it is less error prone when dealing with  dataframes with many columns

Comment: for performing vlookup style assigning you should use `map`, it's designed for this, the only caveat is that the index of the series must be unique which is not an issue when you pass a dict. Also it is fast as you can see

Answer (score 5):

You could use `pd.merge()`

```
In [149]: df1.merge(df2, on='A')
Out[149]:
   A  B
0  a  2
1  a  2
2  b  3
```

Documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: I'd probably go for `on='A'` just to be explicit

Comment: I _knew_ I was missing something. I was playing with .join, but that came out messy as well.

Comment: to be specific, `df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='A')` for changing df1.